# How to show an error message dialogs in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to show an `error messages` or `data validation messages` in Asp.net with c# language.
Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Markup:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
        this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + errorText + "');", true);
}
```

or

```
 Response.Write(
     @"<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=""JavaScript"">alert('" + errorText + "')</SCRIPT>");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to accomplish this, depending your particular situation, but you might try using one of the ASP.NET validation controls, like [RequiredFieldValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.aspx) or [RegularExpressionValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.aspx).

**Example**

```
<asp:TextBox id="textbox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqFldValidator" 
                            runat="server" 
                            ControlToValidate="textbox1" 
                            ErrorMessage="Field is required!" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regExValidator" 
                            runat="server" 
                            ControlToValidate="textbox1" 
                            ValidationExpression="\d+" 
                            ErrorMessage="Must be a number!"/>
```

The preceding ASP.NET markup is all you need to perform a couple of basic validations on a TextBox. If the the form is submitted and the TextBox is blank, the RequiredFieldValidator will preempt the postback and show the message "Field is required!". Similarly, if the text in the TextBox does not match the ValidationExpression of the RegularExpressionValidator, the message "Must be a number!" will be shown.

You can do a lot more with the ASP.NET validation controls, but this is just a basic example. To learn more, consult the MSDN documentation.

Comment: thanks for the answer,presently I'm using the Validation controls, as a beginner in Asp.net I would like to know if this possible or not.

Comment: @Able Alias: I'm sorry, if what is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use te validation summary along with the asp.net validators. Check this [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.validationsummary.aspx) documentation.At the end of the webpage you'll find a nice and easy example how how to use validation summaries.
Happy coding